# Nintendo Miiverse ID Setup Problem

Tags: miiverse, nintendo-network-id

So I recently created a NNID (Miiverse Account) and I have setup everything, i.e email, DOB, region, etc. When I login to miiverse, however, it says

[image: Screenshot of Miiverse]

I would like to know if there are any additional settings I have to do or something like that so that I can login normally. Thank you!

[Edit 1] The Device is a 3DS

Comment: Which device are you doing this on?

Comment: FYI, a credit card is certainly not required.

Comment: Just to be sure: You can log in to Miiverse from the 3DS correctly, but you get the above error on a smartphone or PC?

Comment: @George Yes, I can login to Miiverse from 3ds but can't access it from the PC. I have also seen it automatically sign me in with some games...

Comment: I'm not sure but if I were you I'd contact Nintendo about that.

Answer (score 1):

In the Miiverse settings or in NNID settings on your 3DS, there's an option that allows or denies the use or your NNID outside the 3DS (= on the Miiverse web site).

I can't exactly say where because I don't have mine now, but it exists.

Comment: It's at System Settings > NNID Settings > (Sign in) > Page 3.

Comment: Ok, will try this out...

Comment: Did it work? If yes, that's cool, please consider validating the answer I proposed, it help the community to know which questions are answered and which ones are still waiting for help. :)